# [MAccess]How do I add up figures under the Cost Column which have a specific Course Code,Image provided

Tags: ms-access

[SMS TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCIIE.png)

How do I write a code to sum up the SMS cost per message for a specific course ID
Eg. C0001 = $0.50 + $0.10 + $0.20 ....
I've tried creating a label and changing the control source to

```
=DSum("SMS COST PER MESSAGE","SMS TABLE","COURSE ID = C0001") 
=DSum("SMS COST PER MESSAGE","SMS TABLE","COURSE ID = "C0001"")
```

Error is The expression you have entered contains invalid syntax
You may have entered an operand without an operator

but to no avail
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Field is text type so use apostrophe delimiters. Also, spaces in field and table names so use []. Advise not to use spaces or punctuation/special characters (underscore only exception) in names.

`=DSum("[SMS COST PER MESSAGE]","[SMS TABLE]","[COURSE ID] = 'C0001'")`

Could use doubled quote marks but I find apostrophes easier to read. You judge:

`=DSum("[SMS COST PER MESSAGE]","[SMS TABLE]","[COURSE ID] = ""C0001""")`